# "Antibiotic resistance" equivalent in archaea for selection during cloning

Tags: microbiology, synthetic-biology, cloning, antibiotics, archaea

I'm beginning to work with halophilic archaea and I'm trying to figure out a good way to select for cells that have taken up a plasmid.  Obviously, one can't use antibiotic resistance since they are not bacteria.

**Is there anything equivalent I could use for + selection in cloning experiment for halophilic archaea?** Usually I would use NeoR and Neo plates but that won't work...

Answer (score 5):

> Obviously, one can't use antibiotic resistance since they are not bacteria.

This is not so obvious. Some common antibiotics are active against archaea.<sup>**1**</sup> [The Halohandbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20201214013350/https://haloarchaea.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Halohandbook_2009_v7.3mds.pdf), an indispensable document for the propagation and transformation of Halobacteria, includes a list of selectable markers and their concomitant plasmids:

[image: table from section 3.2.5 of the Halohandbook v7.3]

NovR, MevR, and TmR are genes conferring resistance to novobiocin, mevinolin, and trimethoprim, respectively.

> Usually I would use NeoR and Neo plates but that won't work...

Without knowing the specific organism you are trying to clone, we can't know if neomycin resistance will work as a selectable marker. Indeed, the bacterial neomycin resistance gene *Neo* (encoding aminoglycoside-O-phosphotransferase) can be utilized by mammalian cells to reduce aminoglycoside toxicity<sup>**2**</sup>, so it's not a huge logical jump to assume that archaea could similarly use *Neo*.  If you are working with *Methanococcus*, you can take advantage of vectors encoding aminoglycoside phosphotransferases native to *Methanococcus voltae* to select for neomycin resistance.<sup>**3**</sup>

---

**References**

1. Khelaifia S, Drancourt M. Susceptibility of archaea to antimicrobial agents: applications to clinical microbiology. *Clin Microbiol Infect*. 2012 Sep;18(9):841-8.
2. Dulon D, Ryan AF. The bacterial Neo gene confers neomycin resistance to mammalian cochlear hair cells. *Neuroreport*. 1999 Apr 26;10(6):1189-93.
3. Argyle JL, Tumbula DL, Leigh JA. Neomycin resistance as a selectable marker in *Methanococcus maripaludis*. *Appl Environ Microbiol*. 1996 Nov;62(11):4233-7.